# Is there any way to commit mempool transactions to blockchain?

Tags: mempool

I have thousands of transactions in mempool but not very many have been committed to the blockchain. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear to me what your actual question was. Are you asking why each block does not confirm all waiting transactions at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is there any way to commit mempool transactions to blockchain?**

By mining

> **I have thousands of transactions in mempool but not very many have been committed to the blockchain. Can anyone tell me why?**

That ought to be normal, depending on what time period is involved.

---

Every node keeps a list of unconfirmed transactions in their mempool.

Miners take transactions from their mempool and add them to a new block that they mine. If successful, the new block, and the transactions in it are added to the blockchain.

Approximately every ten minutes, a new block is added to the blockchain. The block can contain two or three thousand transactions. So having thousands of transactions accumulating ought to be normal.

So the only way to move transactions from mempool to blockchain are to wait for them to be mined by a miner.

---

Other relevant questions here with potentially useful answers:

- [Incoming and Outgoing Node Connections](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116967/13866)
- [Bitcoin Core not updating to latest block](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116984/13866)
- [Do I have to open port 8333 for incoming connections?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116716/13866)

Comment: You should clarify. Further. What do you mean by facilitate? Simply operating a Bitcoin core node that allows incoming connections does facilitate the process. How are you measuring the rate of transactions passing through?

Comment: It might be that you are not yet well connected to peers. It might be that your configuration of Bitcoin-core, PC, router or firewall is blocking some connections.

Comment: I just ran netstat and can see active connections. I enabled the default bitcoin port 8333 to allow for connections. I can't think of anything else that might be inhibiting me from connecting to peers.

Comment: What concerns me is that your comments don't seem to be about the "way to commit transactions from mempool to blockchain" in your question title. You seem to be concerned that your node may not be functioning as a full-node properly. Which is a different question really.

Comment: “That ought to be normal, depending on what time period is involved.” > In fact, I’d be shocked if there were any transactions at all that were both in the mempool and in the blockchain. ;)